# How to download a file with ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to download a file with my ionic app, but it's not working, the file is a video file and I want to show a progress bar as its downloading, How it will work is that when a user clicks on download, it will check if the directory `AppName` exist, it not it will create the directory, then download the file inside the directory.

Here's my code

```
download() {
    this.chkmkDir().then(async ()=>{
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.fileTransfer.create();
        this.storageDirectory = `${this.file.dataDirectory}${api.AppName}/`;
        fileTransfer.onProgress((progressEvent)=>this.progress=Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100))
        let fileName=await this.service.getFileName('mp4')
        var URL = encodeURI('test.mp4');
        fileTransfer.download(URL,`${this.storageDirectory}${fileName}`, true)
    })
}
chkmkDir(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        this.file.checkDir(this.file.dataDirectory, api.AppName).then(res=>resolve()
        ).catch(err => {
            this.file.createDir(this.file.dataDirectory, api.AppName,false).then(res =>resolve())
            .catch(err=>reject(JSON.stringify(err))); 
        });
    })
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong, I got this error in the console
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The plugin that you're using is just not there. Your code can't read the classes from the plugin. That may happen due to plugin incompatibility or other dependency issues related to plugins.

This can happen too when you didn't set or configured the plugin properly. Please check your app.module.ts file. And also check if any error related to plugin versions incompatibility is logged in the console. In a brief, all your plugins should have the same version as your **"@ionic-native/core"** version.

Ex:

*package.json*

```
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/dialogs": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/http": "^5.0.0",
```

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work. the problem is in this function `this.file.checkDir(), this.file.createDir()` is not seeing it as a promise, the then method I added to it is what is giving me the error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: this.file.createDir comes from the plugin library which calls the native plugin. Which it's going to be undefined if it's not set properly.

Comment: Try this code: "ionic cordova platform rm android" in your console, and then "ionic cordova platform add android". It will reinstall your Cordova plugins

Comment: I tried it too but I still got the same error message

Comment: Is there any compilation error?. Try to do it with the "ionic cordova run android --device --verbose"

Comment: no, it compiled successully, but its not working in a real device